# Show multiple TextView changes during OnClick

Tags: android

I am currently working on an app which uses Bluetooth, GPS and uploads data to a remote server. I have a simple button which launches a series of events and threads in order to let everything work together.

I am now adding `TextView` components on the screen, which show the user a more detailed process of what is happening. Is the GPS running? Is my Bluetooth device connected? Etc. This process can take up to 10 seconds, this is why I am adding some more information on what is happening on the background.

However, when I click my button, only the last change will be visible. I suppose the `TextView` components are rendered AFTER the `Onclick`?

An example:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     textView.setText(R.string.launching_text);
     // start a thread
     textView.setText(R.string.start_new_thread);
     // start another thread
     textView.setText(R.string.almost_there);
     // start last thread
     textView.setText(R.string.done);
 }
```

Imagine this process taking about 10 seconds. It will look like the app "freezes", but the changes are not visible till after the `OnClick` finishes.

How can I show my information realtime, during the `OnClick` event? Is there perhaps a better practice? Is it possible to do some sort of way to asynchronously push `TextView` changes?

Comment: Use a separate thread and use `runOnUiThread` inside that thread to set the textviews

Comment: So you want to display different messages to user after some seconds?

Comment: use zip operator from Rxjava and combine those observables so that you can show the responses at same time on ui thread, show a progress in meantime. Refer [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

Comment: @WaqasAhmed Exactly. For example I have a `TextView` for Bluetooth connectivity which can have different states: "Connecting...", "Connected", "Failed".

Comment: You can use handler and runnable with a flag to control your TextView behavior after an interval of time and change the color. Also if user click then you can remove the handler further call back and can reset agin as per your requirement.

Comment: @Zoe I tried to create a seperate thread and run it on the `runOnUiThread`, but it doesn't seem to update. However, `Log.i()` shows that the thread is doing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d suggest you first check [this Android Performance Patterns video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z5MZ0jL2BM), to see some of the options at your disposal. I’d also advise to not perform multithreading in a lifecycle environment (e.g. `Activities`, `Fragments`) as this is just asking for trouble.

In your `onClick` example, `R.string.done` could (and most likely will) be displayed before the first thread has done its work. I’m assuming that’s not really what you want.

I have no knowledge of the problem you’re tackling, tools you’re using or the architecture you’re following, so here’s *one* slightly generic way to make it work. Each `Thread` in your `onClick` implementation comes with a status of sorts. You could represent this in code with a simple abstraction:

```
class Holder {
  @StringRes int status;
  Runnable runnable;

  Holder(@StringRes int status, @NonNull Runnable runnable) {
    this.status = status;
    this.runnable = runnable;
  }
}
```

Notice `Runnable` is used instead of `Thread`.

You’re also executing things in sequence. You could represent this in code with a simple `List` or a `Queue`, providing a fluid, expressive API, for example:

```
class StatusRunnableBuilder {
  private final WeakReference<TextView> viewRef;
  private final Queue<Holder> queue;
  @StringRes private int finalStatus;

  StatusRunnableBuilder(@NonNull TextView view) {
    viewRef = new WeakReference<>(view);
    queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
  }

  StatusRunnableBuilder addStep(@StringRes int status,
                                @NonNull Runnable runnable) {
    queue.add(new Holder(status, runnable));
    return this;
  }

  StatusRunnableBuilder withFinalStatus(@StringRes int status) {
    finalStatus = status;
    return this;
  }

  Runnable build() {
    return new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        for (Holder item: queue) {
          updateStatus(item.status);
          item.runnable.run();
        }
        if (finalStatus != 0) {
          updateStatus(finalStatus);
        }
      }
    };
  }

  private void updateStatus(@StringRes final int status) {
    final TextView view = viewRef.get();
    if (view != null) {
      view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // As this has been posted to a queue,
          // it could have been processed with some delay,
          // so there is no guarantee the view is still present.
          // Let's check again.
          final TextView v = viewRef.get();
          if (v != null) {
            v.setText(status);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Then your `onClick` becomes something like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  final Runnable runnable = new StatusRunnableBuilder(view)
    .addStep(R.string.launching_text, launchingRunnable)
    .addStep(R.string.almost_done, almostDoneRunnable)
    .withFinalStatus(R.string.finally_done)
    .build();
  service.execute(runnable);
}
```

where `service` is an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) which allows you to create/shutdown on any lifecycle event, e.g.:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  service.shutdownNow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Runnable` with `Handler`. `Handler` will post updates to `Runnable` after certain intervals.

For Bluetooth connectivity you can go for Broadcast receivers as well.

Comment: I tried using a Runnable, inside the OnClick. The TextView won't update.

Comment: what do you mean by TextView won't update? @Tumladhir

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an AsyncTask. It's pretty simple and it handles all the background threading as well as inter-thread communication for you. There are several considerations with it, to avoid memory leaks you can use EventBus or similar mechanics. Here's an article I found very useful:

http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/